# Access reading violation when trying to use existing struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am writing a program for my class. My program is supposed to create a passenger list. obviously, the list has to be created first, and that option in my program works fine. However when trying to access the second function(pressing B) gives me the following error in the debugger:

> Exception thrown at 0x00CD4A76 in ConsoleApplication13.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

I guess that means I am trying to read into an unallocated area in the memory, therefore, the struct array I am using was not created. I am confused since the first option does work, and I am passing the same pointer to both functions therefore the pointer points to the array created in function A.

```
        #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
using namespace std;

struct date
{
    int year;
    int day;
    int month;
};
struct seat
{
    int row;
    char place;
};

struct pass
{
    char * passname;
    date bookdate;
    seat location;
};
int lastindex;
int initList(pass *p, int x);
int addPass(pass *p, date *D, pass *newpass, int length);

void main()
{
    pass *p = {};
    int length = 0;

    char choice;
    do {
        cout << "Welcome to FlightDesigner2017.\nEnter one of the following keys to continue:\nA: Create a list of passengers.\nB: Add a passenger to the flight.\n";
        cin >> choice;      
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'A':
            {
                int x;
                cout << "How many passengers are on your flight? \n";
                cin >> x;
                length = initList(p, x);
                break;
            }
            case 'B':
            {
                    pass *newpass=0;
                    date *D = 0;
                    switch (addPass(p, D, newpass, length))
                    {
                    case '1':
                        cout << "Passenger successfully added."; break;
                    case '-3':
                        cout << "No seats available."; break;
                    case '-1':
                        cout << "Seat taken. Try again."; break;
                    case '-2':
                        cout << "Passenger is already on the flight."; break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }


    }
    while (choice=!0);
}

int addPass(pass *p, date *D, pass *newpass, int length)
{
#define TAKEN -1
#define SAMENAME -2
#define NOSEATS -3
#define SUCCESS 1
    for (int init = 0; init < length; init++)
    {
        int counter=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) //empty seats check
        {
            if (strcmp(p[j].passname , NULL)!=0)
                counter++;
        }
        if (counter == length)
            return NOSEATS;

        cout << "Enter a seat and row (seat A to F, row 1 to 50): \n";  //taken check
        cin >> newpass->location.place >> newpass->location.row;
        cout << "\nWhat is the flight date (DD/MM/YYYY)? \n";
        cin >> D->day >> D->month >> D->year;
        for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
        {
            if (D->day == p[k].bookdate.day && D->month == p[k].bookdate.month && D->year == p[k].bookdate.year
                && p[k].location.place == newpass->location.place && p[k].location.row == newpass->location.row)
                return TAKEN;
        }


        cout << "What is the passenger name? \n"; // name check
        cin >> newpass->passname;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(newpass->passname,p[i].passname)==0)
                return SAMENAME;
        }

        strcpy(newpass->passname, p[init].passname);
        p[init].location.place = newpass->location.place;
        p[init].location.row = newpass->location.row;
        p[init].bookdate.year = D->year;
        p[init].bookdate.month = D->month;
        p[init].bookdate.day = D->day;

        char ans;
        cout << "Enter another passenger? (Y/N)\n";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == 'N')
            return SUCCESS;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

int initList(pass *p, int length)
{
    p = new pass[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        p[i].passname = NULL;
    return length;
}
```

Any explanation on how can I fix this error will help. thanks in advance.

Comment: ***I guess that means I am trying to read into an unallocated area in the memory*** Looks like you are derefrencing a null pointer.

Comment: Oh its easy to spot. `p` is a null pointer. `int initList(pass *p, int x);` does not change the value of `p` in main since you passed the pointer by value. Change it to `int initList(pass* &p, int x);` to fix.

Comment: Also make `addPass()` check if p is null before continuing.

Comment: In         `strcmp(p[j].passname , NULL)!=0` you are passing NULL pointer as second argument.  the behavior is undefined when you pass NULL pointer or at best implementation dependent. Since you are not comparing actual strings and checking if the pointer is pointing to nothing, consider using a equality operator something like  `p[j].passname == NULL` .

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string` and `std::unique_ptr`? It will make your life so much easier.

Comment: Using strings and cin.getline didn't seem to please my teacher for some odd reason. I am getting runtime errors when trying to write data into the array: 
 
Exception thrown: write access violation.
_Ch was 0x14.

Comment: When the exception is caught break and walk up the callstack to the line of your code that caused the access violation.

Comment: @Tommy _"... didn't seem to please my teacher for some odd reason."_ LOL, you're a righteous guy, [just send 'em over](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2015/02/software-development-in-wild-i-have.html)